# Messages not appears correctly in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm writing a messaging app that show mine and other message in RecyclerView.

White background message is Mine message and colored messages is other message.

When each message is sequentially like " Mine Message, Other Message, ..." the recycler view shows correct.
Like below.[image]

But when message sequence like "Other message, Other message, Mine message" the recycler view shows Mine message as other and vice versa.
Like below
[image]

I used this code for `onBindViewHolder`

```
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View v;
        int width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (width * 0.75), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if(getItemViewType(i) == MINE){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_message_view_mine, viewGroup, false);
            v.setX((float) (width * 0.23));
        }else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_message_view, viewGroup, false);
            v.setX(0);
        }

        layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.e("pos", position + "");
        try{
            if(items.get(position).isResponse()){
                return MINE;
            }else {
                return OTHERS;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return OTHERS;
        }



    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if(getItemViewType(i) == OTHERS){
        if(items.get(i).getResponse() != null){
            viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.green_1, R.color.green_2);
        }else {
            if(items.get(i).getDate() - System.currentTimeMillis() /1000 > 100){
                viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.red_1, R.color.red_2);
            }else {
                viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.yellow_1, R.color.yellow_2);
            }
        }

    }

        if(!items.get(i).isResponse()){
            if(items.get(i).getResponse() != null){
                viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.green_1, R.color.green_2);
            }else {
                int type = General.currentUser.getCurrentRole().getType();
                int timeOut = 0;
                if(type == Role.OPERATOR){
                    timeOut = General.operatorTimeOut;
                }else if(type == Role.EXPERT || type == Role.CO_EXPERT){
                    timeOut = General.expertTimeOut;
                }else if(type == Role.SENDER){
                    timeOut = General.senderTimeOut;
                }else if(type == Role.VERIFIER){
                    timeOut = General.verifierTimeOut;
                }

                if((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - items.get(i).getDate() > timeOut){
                    viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.red_1, R.color.red_2);
                }else {
                    viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.yellow_1, R.color.yellow_2);
                }
            }
        }else {
            viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColors(R.color.white, R.color.grey);
        }

        if(items.get(i).getType() == Message.TYPE_VOICE && items.get(i).getVoice() != null){
            viewHolder.layoutVoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.tvText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //if(items.get(i).getVoice().get)
            File voice = new File(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + items.get(i).getVoice().getId());
            if(voice.exists()){
                viewHolder.playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.ivVoice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(playerItem != -1){
                    if(playerItem == i){
                        viewHolder.playerView.startAnimation((int) items.get(i).getVoice().getLength(), new PlayerView.PlayerViewListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPlayerFinished() {

                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        viewHolder.playerView.stopAnimation();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                viewHolder.playerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.ivVoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            viewHolder.tvVoiceVolume.setText((items.get(i).getVoice().getVolume() / 1024) + " KB");
            viewHolder.tvVoiceLength.setText((items.get(i).getVoice().getLength() /60) + ":" + (items.get(i).getVoice().getLength() %60) + " s");


        }else {
            viewHolder.layoutVoice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.tvText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.tvText.setText(items.get(i).getText());
        }

        if(items.get(i).isResponse()){
            viewHolder.ivSent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(items.get(i).getSendStatus() == Message.SENT){
                viewHolder.ivSent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                viewHolder.ivSent.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
            }else if(items.get(i).getSendStatus() == Message.SENDING) {
                viewHolder.ivSent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_query_builder_black_24dp);
                viewHolder.ivSent.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY);
            }else if(items.get(i).getSendStatus() == Message.FAILED){
                viewHolder.ivSent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp);
                viewHolder.ivSent.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
            }
        }else {
            if(items.get(i).getUnder_user_role_process1() > 0){
                viewHolder.ivSent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.ivSent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_verified_user_black_24dp);
                viewHolder.ivSent.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
            }else {
                viewHolder.ivSent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }



        Date date = new Date(items.get(i).getDate() * 1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH); // the format of your date
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4:30")); // give a timezone reference for formatting (see comment at the bottom
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

        viewHolder.tvDate.setText(formattedDate);

    }
```

What's problem?

Comment: add onBindViewHolder too

Comment: @VladMatvienko I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem.
onCreateViewHolder's second parameter is viewType not a position.
So the `i` in onCreateViewHolder is viewType. So I changed `if(getItemViewType(i) == MINE)` to `if(i == MINE)` after it every thing gone ok.

Answer (score 1):

I first think about the users not have a like "UserID" so then when u type 2 messages in row u will get a bug like every message will be on one side. And why u use recyclerView? not better is create a layout with like "Scroll View" and adding for this a views(messages) ?

```
private long createRandomId() {
    char[] chars = "123456789".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return Long.parseLong(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: RecyclerView is more better than other ways. But when I feel that should use it so I will use it

Comment: As u wish, if u need helped i will help you with my own chat that i create using a scrollView, also see edited post for create a randomId for user

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter that problem sir but I solve it using separate view holders.

```
  @Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    UserViewHolder holder = null ;
    int layoutRes = 0;
    switch (viewType) {
        case CURRENT_USER_VIEW:
            layoutRes = R.layout.current_user_view_model;
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, parent, false);
            holder = new CurrentUserHolder(view);
            break;
        case OTHER_USER_VIEW:
            layoutRes = R.layout.sender_user_view_model;
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, parent, false);
            holder = new SenderUserHolder(view);
            break;
    }

    return  holder;
}

 public abstract class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

public class SenderUserHolder extends  UserViewHolder{
    public TextView message;
    public TextView dateSent;
    public ImageView senderImage;
    public final View mView;
    public View contSender;

    public SenderUserHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        contSender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_sender);
        message = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
        dateSent = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_send_date);
        senderImage = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.iv_send_image);
    }
}

public class CurrentUserHolder extends  UserViewHolder{
    public TextView message;
    public TextView dateSent;
    public final View mView;
    public View cont;;

    public CurrentUserHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        cont = mView.findViewById(R.id.cont_current);
        message = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
        dateSent = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_send_date);
    }
}
```